# How to make Spark standalone make effective utilization of an AWS autoscaling cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, autoscaling

We have Spark standalone cluster running on AWS autoscaling worker instances. Is there a way in Spark we can configure resource manager to make use of a new worker only once all the resources on existing ones are exhausted.

This is required because we often see a scenario where there are 6 active workers and only very few cores are in use but across all workers. This makes cluster under utilized. If it would have allocated all cores on one worker and then move on to the other only after using all resources on one worker , scale down policy would have terminated idle worker and thus saving $$$.